# Unity 5.2 --- Animator window / tab

Tags: unity, mecanim

I have downloaded the latest `Unity 5.2.0f3` so I wondered if it is just me or others are having a similar problem: When I double-click on an `animator controller` to launch it, the animator tab/window appears, but when I run the editor, I don't get the usual flow, operations, etc... I only get a static view of the states and transition arrows between them. My parameters do not show the changes they go through either.

I have multiple animations and can switch between them when certain game conditions occur, but nothing really shows when I do so, to see the flow of control, what happens, what goes wrong, the switching, the progress bar, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the age old problem. Don't know whether it can be called a problem tho :P . So what you need to do is , once you start play in the editor , and have the animator window docked on one side. Just go and click the object in the hierarchy for which you want to analyse the animation flow. And the animator window will start showing the states and the progress bar.